# Simplifying square root with fraction

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

I'm not sure about this equality $$4(-3+\sqrt {15})/4)^2 = (9-6 \sqrt{15} +15)/4$$

Hope some one can enlighten me. I will be facing more of such fractions, please guide me on how to solve/simplify in easy method.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’ll even finish the simplification:

$$\begin{align*}
4\left(\frac{-3+\sqrt{15}}4\right)^2&=4\cdot\frac{(-3+\sqrt{15})(-3+\sqrt{15}}{4\cdot4}\\
&=\frac{(-3)^2+2(-3)\sqrt{15}+(\sqrt{15})^2}4\\
&=\frac{9-6\sqrt{15}+15}4\\
&=\frac{24-6\sqrt{15}}4\\
&=6-\frac32\sqrt{15}\;.
\end{align*}$$

In short: cancel a factor of $4$, and multiply out the numerator.

Comment: Hi Brian,thanks for the fast response and explanation. 

Initially I do something like -3 ^2 and sqroot 15 ^ 2. Now I see a clearer picture that you are using expansion (correct me If I use the terms wrongly). 

Would appreciate if you can explain the last two row of your simplification? I'm not sure how you remove the fraction.

Thanks :)

Comment: @Withhelds: You’re welcome. In the expansion of the numerator I used the identity $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$. At the end I left out an intermediate step that might make it clearer: $$\frac{24-6\sqrt{15}}4=\frac{24}6-\frac{6\sqrt{15}}4=6-\frac64\sqrt{15}= 6-\frac32\sqrt{15}\;.$$ Does that help?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure on how you get 24/6 to - (6 * sqroot 15) /4. Is it by moving -6 (second value on the numerator) to the denominator so that it become positive 6?

Comment: @Withhelds: No, that’s a stupid typo. It should be $\frac{24}4$.

Comment: Oh I see, I finally understand. Thanks for your great and prompt help once again! :)

Comment: @Withhelds: You’re welcome!